# how to disable kvm for installing VMware player

Tags: vmware, kvm-virtualization

when i was going to install VMware player a massage has shown `You can not install a system with KVM enable`. My processor is amd phenom ii x6 1100t. so how can i disable KVM on my system.

I am actually a new in Linux world. sorry for my bad English and thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [KVM/FAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/FAQ)

Answer (score 6):

Unload the module. Type,

```
lsmod
```

to see where it is loaded.

mine was,

```
...
kvm_intel             143109  0 
kvm                   451552  1 kvm_intel
```

so I did,

```
sudo rmmod kvm_intel kvm
```

and then the installer worked.