# disable and enable KVM on demand?

Tags: 14.04, kvm-virtualization

Thanks to this great site, I think that I know [how to disable KVM](https://askubuntu.com/a/539800/363039) for the purpose of installing/running VMWare:

```
sudo rmmod kvm_intel kvm
```

Now, if I want to re-enable it (without rebooting Ubuntu, that is), what is the best way to accomplish this?

Is it as simple as a single reverse command:

```
sudo insmod kvm-intel
```

or do I need something else in addition to this?

(trying to double-check before I try something irreversible on my machine... Thanks.)